# Why doesn't my function list all the properties of an Array but does on ob?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code. My function doesn't work on the object `Array` but does on my object `ob` defined with an object literal.

```js
function all_properties(object) {
 var value = "[";
 for (var prop in object) {
  
   value += '"' + prop + '"' + ","
 }
 value = value.slice(0,-1);
 value += "]";
 return value;
}

var ob = {first: 1, second: function () {}, third: function () {}}
console.log(all_properties(ob))
console.log(all_properties(Array))
```

Comment: You should use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Where did you defined the Array which you used in the last line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most built-in objects, the properties of the `Array` constructor (which is not an array) are marked as [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties), so `for in` won't see them.

Use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` to see *all* properties.

Comment: Also `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` works. What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` is going to return a new object, with properties from the given object and descriptors (like if it is writable, enumerable etc) and `.getOwnPropertyNames()` will return an array with only the property names. `.getOwnPropertyNames()` is much more commonly used

Comment: @LearningMath: See the documentation.